# how to programmatically invalidate captured simulation stubs dynamically

Tags: hoverfly

I am using hoverfly for service virtualization purpose for testing our microservices. In a particular scenario when a service endpoint response is changed (contractually) for eg: the format of date is changed, my test cases still pass when it's consuming already captured simulation which doesn't have this minor change in its stub. I am trying to see how can I still keep my stubs up to date in such situations? does hoverfly reload the simulation stub if there is a change in service response?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's a bit late to answer.

> does hoverfly reload the simulation stub if there is a change in service response?

No it does not. You would have to do `hoverctl import simulation.json` for hoverfly to pick up the changes. Assuming, you have updated the simulation.json with the new changes.

> how can I still keep my stubs up to date in such situations?

I would suggest writing a simple python script, which can do the changes for you to the simulation.json as an when required. You can get more fancy with [something like this](https://github.com/Navdit/hoverfly_stub_framework). However, I believe in your case it's a bit of an overkill and a simple python script should suffice.